# Extracting tar.gz file on Heroku

Tags: heroku

I got a task to deploy my app on Heroku.

My app is a tar.gz file that I extract and a command line I need to run.

How can that be deployed to Heroku?

All I can find in the documentation is git repository references.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku uses git as it's deployment mechanism. You will have to extract your tar file locally, initialize a git repo within the directory, and then deploy that to Heroku.